# UIWebview frame is not resizing to it's content

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

I have a `NSString` that contains `HTML tags`. So for showing it correctly I'm using a `UIWebview`. Now I want to resize the UIWebview its frame to fit the content. I'm adding this `UIWebview` to a `tableHeader`. Now this is what I do.

In my viewDidLoad

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, height2,self.view.bounds.size.width-30, 20)];
    [[webView scrollView] setBounces: NO];
    webView.delegate = self;
    [self.headerView addSubview:webView];

    [self setWebDescription:webView];
```

Then in setWebDescription

```
-(void)setWebDescription:(UIWebView *)webDescription
{
    NSString *myDescriptionHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> \n"
                                   "<head> \n"
                                   "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
                                   "body {font-family: \"%@\"; font-size:15; font-color:\"%@\";}\n"
                                   "</style> \n"
                                   "</head> \n"
                                   "<body>%@</body> \n"
                                   "</html>",@"TeutonNormal",@"#AAAAAA", _newsItem.new_body];
    [webDescription setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [webDescription setOpaque:NO];
    [webDescription loadHTMLString:myDescriptionHTML baseURL:nil]; 
}
```

And finally in my webViewDidFinishLoad

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {
    CGRect newBounds = aWebView.bounds;
    [aWebView sizeToFit];
    newBounds.size.height = aWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height;
    aWebView.bounds = newBounds;
    aWebView.scrollView.bounds = newBounds;
    aWebView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;

    NSLog(@"Height is %f",newBounds.size.height);

    newHeight =  height2 + aWebView.frame.size.height;


    UILabel *lblLikes = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, newHeight+10, 160, 40)];
    lblLikes.text = _newsItem.new_publishdate;

    float newHeight2 =  newHeight + 80;
    NSLog(@"new height header is %f",newHeight2);
    [self.headerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.size.width,newHeight2)];
        [headerView addSubview:lblLikes];

    [self.tableView setBounces:NO];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
```

I also add below the webview another label. The problem is now that my webview is always 20px high like I set in the `viewDidLoad`. So it does not fit the content.

Can anybody help me with this ?

Comment: UIWebView is scrollable, so you need to calculate the height yourself or use a fixed height.

Comment: Don't I do this with this line? --> newBounds.size.height = aWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height;

Comment: UIWebView is a bit funny, I suggest trying the Javascript route instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following type to get the content height of `UIWebView`,

```
CGFloat newHeight = [[self.answerWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.scrollHeight;"] floatValue];
```

Hope it will helps you..